# How Decorator pattern works in c++

Tags: c++, decorator

I hope this is not a duplicate, and sorry for my not perfect english.

I'm trying to understand how exactly the decorator pattern works in c++.

I'm using [this](https://gist.github.com/dlivingstone/3006324#file-decoratormain-cpp-L31) implementation found online and the design is clear to me.

What i can't understand is how technically it's working.

When i'm creating a new object and decorating it, for example:

```
AbstractNPC *goblin1= new Elite(new Shaman(new NPC("Goblin")));
```

The type of goblin1 will be Elite, Shaman, NPC or what?

And how the function render() "takes" the implementation of the other classes and use them together?

I would expect that when i call render(), i'm calling recursively the functions from the other decorator classes using this instruction:

```
NPCDecorator::render();
```

Still this doesn't make sense to me.

How and why this works?

Comment: Are you familiar with  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Polymorphic_objects  and  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions  ?

Comment: N.b. that example is bad C++. `new` should be absent from normal code, and should always be matched with `delete` where it is present

Comment: @PiotrNycz Yes i'm familiar with these concepts, but evidently not enough. I will read tha pages more carefully, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *relevant* type of `goblin1` is right there in the declaration, `AbstractNPC *`.

`NPCDecorator` *implements* this abstract class by holding on to *another* instance of that abstract class. In the expression `new Elite(new Shaman(new NPC("Goblin")))` there are *three* `AbstractNPC` instances, two decorators and a "normal" instance.

When the virtual call `render` comes into the first decorator, it does it's stuff, then call's its base classes `render`, which just delegates to the decorated `npc` member.

You will have a call stack like:

```
Elite::render
{
    // this == Elite * @ 0x12345678
    cout << "Elite ";
    NPCDecorator::render
    {
        Shaman::render
        {
            // this == Shaman * @ 0x56781234
            cout << "Shaman ";
            NPCDecorator::render
            {
                NPC::render
                {
                    // this == NPC * @ 0x78563412
                    cout << name; // "Goblin"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uao, this is great. Thank you Caleth, this answer is really clear!
Regarding your comment about the new, what should i use in substitution of the new?

Comment: Switch `AbstractNPC *` for `std::unique_ptr<AbstractNPC>` and use e.g. `std::unique_ptr<AbstractNPC> goblin1 = std::make_unique<Elite>(std::make_unique<Shaman>(std::make_unique("Goblin")));`